# is<thing> equivalents for char32_t

Tags: c++, char32-t

Are there any equivalents for the char functions (ispace, isalpha, etc) defined in `<ctype>` for `char32_t`?

I had a look around & could only see iswspace (& related) which seem like those are for 16bit chars.

Note: while isspace takes a int as a parameter it seems to produce erroneous results for Unicode characters.

Example:

```cpp
char32_t dagger = U'';
if (isspace(dagger)) {
    puts("That is a space!");
}
```

Will output "That is a space!"

Comment: The `isalpha()` set of functions take an `int` parameter - so, if your compiler uses 32-bit integers as default, then a `char32_t` argument shouldn't present a problem.

Comment: It seems to fail for Unicode characters. For example it returns true when given 128481 (which I think is a dagger emoji).

Comment: Posting an example showing that

Comment: Actually, just after I posted my comment, it occurred to me that simply interpreting a `char32_t` as an `int` would probably not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Up to `wchar_t` you can use [std::isalpha](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/isalpha) with the suitable locale defined in in `<locale>`.

For anything above 0xFFFF you will need the ICU library:

[u_isalpha](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4c/uchar_8h.html#a86cc4f937e33bcea3772c6faf3e293c1) or [u_isUAlphabetic](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4c/uchar_8h.html#a43cbdd6f7dc28705600c8234e4d47f6f)

[u_isspace](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4c/uchar_8h.html#a9e5a0b4c0d3f1ce71e185afc12cb1645) or [u_isUWhiteSpace](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4c/uchar_8h.html#a3450f489a9a41e5bb199aded7a2b74d3)

Full list of functions: [uchar.h](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4c/uchar_8h.html#func-members)

Answer (score 0):

While C++-the-language has facilities for generating Unicode values, C++-the-library is almost completely deaf to Unicode. `<ctype.h>` and `<cctype>` have no idea how to handle Unicode values; their functionality is based on the [C locale mechanism](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/clocale). Your implementation may provide locales that know what Unicode is, but the `"C"` locale that is the default is not one of them.

Comment: So is it best just to create my own list of space characters?

Comment: @user3818491: The "best" thing would be to use a Unicode library like ICU.

Comment: Yeah,  but I don't really want something so big for such a little thing.

Comment: @user3818491: If you care enough about Unicode to want to accurately ask whether a codepoint counts as whitespace, then you will likely *eventually* want to ask other Unicode questions. Better to go with a tool that you might not fully utilize than to have to create ad-hoc solutions that may not be correct.

Comment: Fair point, I'm already using utf8-cpp for basic parsing but maybe I do need something more.